# Azure Log Analytics Query for CPU performace stats by each process

Tags: windows, azure, performance, cpu-usage, azure-log-analytics

I need Azure Log Analytics Query to Plot a time analysis of CPU consumed by each process in Azure VM.

Our Azure VM's are under Leagacy agent management and we only had one processer performace counter
Processor(_Total)% Processor Time

Do we need to any other performace counter to extract the infromation

FYI our VM's are completely windows

Please help me with finding the query and confiuration for the same

I Have tried with below query

```
Perf
| where ObjectName == "Process" and CounterName == "% Processor Time" and InstanceName != "_Total"
| summarize AvgCPU = avg(CounterValue) by InstanceName, bin(TimeGenerated, 1m)
| render timechart
```

result which says no data available in the timerange

later i checked with below

```
Perf
| where ObjectName == "Process" and CounterName == "% Processor Time" and InstanceName != "_Total"
| render table
```

same result which says no data available in the timerange

Beacuse the perf table has _total records only and may be it was related to performace counter

I need solution for this

Thank
Radha

Answer (score 0):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and below is the result**

> Our Azure VMs are under Leagacy agent management and we only had one processer performance counter Processor(_Total)% Processor Time

Make sure that the **% Processor Time** performance counter is enabled on your VM. You can check this by going to the **Performance Monitor** on your **VM** and looking for the **% Processor Time** counter under the Process object. If it's not there, you will need to add it to the list of performance counters by the below steps.

1. log in to your **Windows VM**
2. Open **Performance Monitor**
3. Once open the performance monitor click on **"+"** in the tool bar and **Processor counter** as bel**ow.**

[image]

Performance result after adding processor counter.

[image]

4. Add a performance counter in **Log Analytics Workspace**, if you are using legacy agent management by following the steps.

**Go to Azure Portal > Log Analytics workspaces > Select your LAW > Legacy agents management > Windows performance counters**

[image]

Now check the result.

```
Perf
| where ObjectName == "Process" and CounterName == "% Processor Time" and InstanceName != "_Total"
| summarize AvgCPU = avg(CounterValue) by InstanceName, bin(TimeGenerated, 1m)
| render timechart
```

**Output:**

[image]

```
Perf
| where ObjectName == "Process" and CounterName == "% Processor Time" and InstanceName != "_Total"
| render table
```

**Output:**

[image]